# objective-c : what is the equivalent of java Math.toRadians(EndLat - StartLat) in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, math, radians

what is the equivalent of java function

```
Double EndLat;
Double StartLat;
Math.toRadians(EndLat - StartLat);
```

in objective-c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>

(EndLat - StartLat) * M_PI / 180.0;
```

You might want to put this in a function if you're going to be using it a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well Math.toRadians(a) seems to compute the radians from the angle a.

According to any sufficient basic math text, the equivalent code would be

result = a * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0